# Scheduled Backup Influx Data Inside Docker using Cron

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cron, influxdb

I have this interesting problem at work involving an influxDB image for Docker (version 2.2). The objective is using a CRON scheduler to execute a Bash script that backups all data, considering that it uses an "influx backup" command. Is there a way of initializing the CRON deamon without affecting the influxDB (running independently), using the tools provided by the influxDB Docker image? I know I'm killing the concept of Microservices, but with this ideia working, it would be a lot better than another cronjob dedicated container, apart from the fact that I would have to deal with volume sharing problems and lack of influx engine commands to execute the backup from another container. Throwing another question, is there a more optimized way to do this backup with a scenario of one influx container and a cronjob container?

Is there a way to do it with supervisord?

I tried to activate the Cron deamon manually, inside the container, but that generated a lot of defunct process inside the container. I was expecting that the cron process would run and call the Bash routines independently.